# Finding a word with the most consecutive vowels in a text file, using Java

Tags: java

I have a problem in Java that must be solved without anything but the most basic code. It cannot include arrays, and I can't really import anything other than what's showing in my code. The question is this:

The file words.txt on the book’s website contains 87,314 words from the English language.
Write a program that reads through this file and finds the word that has the most consecutive vowels.

I'm brand new to programming, so I've got some ideas of what to do but not precisely how to put it all together. I'm really stuck on this question. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's what I've come up with, but it's clearly incorrect, and I've already spent many hours on it, including researching here and other places, and trying the code I found. I'm not expecting anyone to do the homework for me, but if you could give me some guidance, it would be very much appreciated. Here's what I have so far:

```
package vowels;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Vowels
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner fileIn = null;
        try
        {
            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("words.txt")); 
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String eachWord = fileIn.next();
        String mostConsecutiveVowels = "";
        int w = 0;
        int z;
        int consecutiveVowels = 0;
        int mostConsecutiveVowelsInWord = 0;
        int wordWithMostConsecutiveVowels = 0;
        boolean vowel;
        boolean previousVowel;
        boolean mostVowels;

        while (fileIn.hasNext())
        {
            while(consecutiveVowels >= mostConsecutiveVowelsInWord)
            {
                mostVowels = true;
            }

            char a = eachWord.charAt(w);
            if (a=='a'||a=='e'||a=='i'||a=='o'||a=='u')
            {
               consecutiveVowels++;
               consecutiveVowels = mostConsecutiveVowelsInWord;
            }


            for(z = 1; z <= eachWord.length(); z++)
            {
                char b = eachWord.charAt(z);
                char c = eachWord.charAt(z-1);

                while (b=='a'||b=='e'||b=='i'||b=='o'||b=='u')
                {
                    vowel = true;
                }

                while (c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u')
                {
                    previousVowel = true;
                }

                if (vowel = false && previousVowel = true && mostVowels = false;)
                {
                    consecutiveVowels = 0;
                }
                else if (vowel = false && previousVowel = true && mostVowels = true;)
                {
                    consecutiveVowels = mostConsecutiveVowelsInWord;
                }
                else if (vowel = true && previousVowel = false)
                {
                    consecutiveVowels = 1;   
                }
                else if (vowel = true && previousVowel = true && mostVowels = true;)
                {
                    consecutiveVowels++;
                    consecutiveVowels = mostConsecutiveVowelsInWord;
                }
                else if (vowel = true && previousVowel = true && mostVowels = false;)
                {
                    consecutiveVowels++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (mostVowels)
        {   
            if(eachWord.length()>mostConsecutiveVowels.length())
            {
                mostConsecutiveVowels = eachWord;
            }
        }
            System.out.println("The word in words.txt with the most consecutive vowels is " + mostConsecutiveVowels);
                fileIn.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: For problems like this, I think it is best to work it by hand first.  Then go through the steps you did by hand and put those into the program.  You have a typical beginners problem that there's *way too much stuff* in your program.  You need to think about the problem, only about half the lines in your algorithm are really needed.

Comment: +1 for what markspace said. I would add that if you could break your problem into separate methods it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. However, you should try coming up with your own as well for practice, and if you want to use the comments in my code as suggestions.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowels {

  public static final String WORD_FILE = "words.txt";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(WORD_FILE))) {
      String targetWord = null; // word with most consecutive vowels
      int maxConsecutiveVowels = 0;
      while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        // for each word in the file
        String word = fileScanner.next().toLowerCase();
        int consecutiveVowels = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() && i < word.length() - maxConsecutiveVowels + consecutiveVowels; i++) {
          // for each character in the word, and exit early if the word is not long enough to beat maxConsecutiveVowels
          if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
            // consonants reset this to 0
            consecutiveVowels++;
          } else {
            // reached the end of the vowels so check if we beat maxConsecutiveVowels
            if (consecutiveVowels > maxConsecutiveVowels) {
              maxConsecutiveVowels = consecutiveVowels;
              targetWord = word;
            }
            consecutiveVowels = 0;
          }
        }
        // reached the end of the vowels at the end of the word so check if we beat maxConsecutiveVowels
        if (consecutiveVowels > maxConsecutiveVowels) {
          maxConsecutiveVowels = consecutiveVowels;
          targetWord = word;
        }
      }
      if (targetWord == null) {
        System.out.println("there are no words with vowels in " + WORD_FILE);
      } else {
        System.out.println("the word in " + WORD_FILE + " with the most consecutive vowels is '" + targetWord + "'");
        System.out.println("it has " + maxConsecutiveVowels + " consecutive vowels");
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am so new here that I'm not sure if I'm commenting correctly in my own thread (this was my first question asked on Stack Overflow), but a big thanks to everyone who responded (I'm only allowed to tag one person), and a huge thanks to @nmore for the extremely helpful answer.

I talked with another student after class tonight, and he said the same thing that markspace said, that I made it way too complicated. So I had gotten as far as removing all booleans (I used if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') to see if character was a vowel) and using for and if else. Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, and unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to vote up the answer yet. I plan to, if and when I get enough rep. Subtracting maxConsecutiveVowels  and adding consecutiveVowels to word.length in the for loop was the missing piece. I was getting a word with three consecutive vowels before that. @nmore, your code is elegant and inspirational. I clearly have a lot to learn, and I plan to work hard and learn it!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, but I have a lot to learn too. Good luck.

Comment: My pleasure! I've been thinking about your code off and on since I last wrote. I don't completely understand how

Comment: Hmm, I think I don't understand how comments work. Should this be another answer? Here's what I meant to say:
@nmore, I've been thinking about your code off and on since I last wrote. I don't completely understand how
    i < word.length() && i < word.length() - maxConsecutiveVowels + consecutiveVowels
works. I can see the result works - it's brilliant - but I've been trying it out with pen and paper and still can't see how it works.

Comment: Also, I discovered tonight that the file contains 3 words with 5 consecutive vowels each (cooeeing, miaoued & queueing), and none with 6. So, the instructions are incomplete: they say find "the" word with 5 consecutive vowels.
I figured out that if I change 
    if (consecutiveVowels > maxConsecutiveVowels)
in the for loop to 
    if (consecutiveVowels >= maxConsecutiveVowels)
I get the last word with the most consecutive vowels instead of the
first word with the most consecutive vowels. I really want to figure out how to get all three words to show up, but I have other homework due tomorrow..

Comment: Hopefully the i < word.length() part makes sense, but I'll explain the second half. Suppose we already found a word with 6 consecutive vowels, so maxConsecutiveVowels is 6. Then if we start checking a new word (i=0, consecutiveVowels=0) with length 6, the condition will be 0<6-6+0 (false). Therefore loop won't be entered because there are not enough characters left in the new word to beat 6 consecutive vowels. If the new word is 7 long, then the first letter has to be a vowel so that at i=1 and consecutiveVowels=1 the condition will be 1<7-6+1 (keep checking), or else it will be 1<7-6+0 (bail)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @nmore!
Hopefully I'm not making a fool of myself here, but it looks to me like consecutiveVowels only resets if it encounters a consonant. So when we start checking a new word, consecutiveVowels isn't necessarily 0.
If consecutiveVowels is always 0 at the start of a new word, why would we need the
    +consecutiveVowels
part of 
    i < word.length() - maxConsecutiveVowels + consecutiveVowels;?

Otherwise, your explanation makes complete sense, thanks!

Comment: The "int consecutiveVowels = 0;" right before the character for-loop resets consecutiveVowels. Also, we need the +consecutive vowels part so that we don't exit the loop too early if there is a chance to beat maxConsecutiveVowels. From my 7 letter example above trying to beat 6 vowels, without the +consecutive part the condition will fail too early at i=1 (1<7-6) even if the first letter was a vowel and the word has the potential to beat 6 vowels. Therefore we want to check if i<7-6+consecutiveVowels which will keep going if the first letter was a vowel (1<7-6+1)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and patient explanation, @nmore, I really appreciate it. I completely missed the "int consecutiveVowels = 0;" right before the character for-loop; I understand that part now.
It turns out I didn't completely understand how for-loops work. I didn't realize that while the for-loop was going through the current loop, it would be adding consecutive vowels from the current word to the for statement (if I'm using the terms correctly). I thought it was using the previous word's count (that is, zero, since it was reset) for consecutive vowels. I get it now, thanks!!